# Laravel excel read xls like html

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using in my program Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel package to import xls/xlsx files. In most of the case the import go good, and the program read perfectly the rows so how they are in the file. But sometimes it reads rows just like if they are including in html tag. This depending by package or by xls file creation?

This is how should return:
[image: Photo1]

This is instead how it returns:
[image: Photo2]

**UPDATE: MY CODE**

```
public function preparaCampiMappaturaXLS($riga_inizio_importazione, $intestazione, $file) {
    $res = null;
    Excel::load($file, function($reader) use($riga_inizio_importazione, $intestazione, &$res) {
        $sheet = $reader->first()->toArray();

        // Calcolo l'indice da cui estrapolare i campi da far visualizzare per la mappatura
        if ($intestazione) {
            $index = $riga_inizio_importazione - 2;
        } else {
            $index = $riga_inizio_importazione - 1;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($index, $sheet)) {
            throw new \App\Exceptions\InvalidIndexException("La riga selezionata non è presente all'interno del file");
        }

        $res = $sheet[$index];
    });

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Compare both files and look for the differences. The code will not magically change. Maybe it's a different version of excel. If you need help you can also show us the code?

Comment: Was the excel file saved as html? I think ony xlsx works (xls has different format too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel package is working fine for you, You can replace from

```
 $res = $sheet[$index];
```

To

```
 $res = trim(strip_tags($sheet[$index]));
```